# How to check the existance of a value from asp designer page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm getting a list of string from db like:

```
AddCustomer,
AddUser,
ListCustomer,
ListUser
```

These are the prefix of asp pages. 
I need to hide and show certain pages in the page. Following is the html snippet:

```
<li>Customer Management
                    <ul>
                        <%if (AddCustomer)  //how to check whether my string is present or not, is it possible?
                          { %><li><a href="AddCustomer.aspx">Add Customer</a></li><%} %>
                        <li><a href="ListCustomer.aspx">List Customer</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

Comment: You mean you need to hide and show links not pages on your aspx page based on the string list you are getting from the DB. right?

Comment: you need to start for how you get values from your database... do you have done that ? Do you use any DAL like linq ? If not, learn about them first.

Comment: @ebad86 Yes,that's what i mean

Comment: @Aristos I am using LinQ bt how can that be helpful in aspx designer page?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried writing method then calling it from aspx page?

```
<%# YourMethodName((string)Eval("AddCustomer")) %>
```